# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

**Все собираются у нас в доме, все веселятся(,) и все довольны.**

Answer (score 1):

Да, по правилам запятая нужна: это сложное предложение, состоящее из трех частей (грамматические основы: все собираются; все веселятся; все довольны), с бессоюзной и сочинительной связью. Здесь нет общих второстепенных членов предложения, которые бы влияли на постановку запятой. Поэтому запятая должна быть: "*Все собираются у нас в доме, все веселятся, и все довольны*".